# MongoDB NodeJS Native cursor closing prematurely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-cursor

I'm executing a process to each element of a ursor, my collection has around 6 million documents, the entire process would take up to 10 hours since I have to process a profile at a time and it's a somewhat complex process for each one.

```
 var cursor = dbMain.collection("profiles").find({});

 var getNext = function(){
      cursor.nextObject(processOne);
 };

 var processOne = function(err, profile){
      if(err){
           console.error("Error loading profile", err);
           getNext();
      } else if(profile == null){
           // process is done, all profiles processed!!!
      } else {
           processProfile(profile)
               .then(function(){
                    getNext();
               })
               .catch(function(errProfile){
                    console.error("Error processing profile", errProfile);
                    getNext();
               });
      }
 };

 var processProfile = function(profile){
      // Complex profile processing and promise resolve when done
 };

 getNext();
```

PROBLEM: I get null (which would mean the cursor has been exhausted) when i'm around 300,000 profiles, so, only the first 300,000 or so get processed. ¿Anyone knows how to deal with it or the reason I'm getting null way before time?

Comment: I hope your system is 64bit, right?

Comment: Yeah, it's fine, no hardware or installation issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems I've found the reason:

Since it's a cursor that needs to be alive a long time, in the find options I had to add "timeout : false".

```
 var cursor = dbMain.collection("profiles").find({}, {timeout : false});
```

In the [driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) says it's false by default (well it's not!!) , now all of my profiles get processed.

Comment: Hey, guy,I have read the source code, but finally found the code: `if(typeof newOptions.timeout == 'boolean') newOptions.noCursorTimeout = newOptions.timeout;` and `if(self.s.options.noCursorTimeout == true) {
    self.addCursorFlag('noCursorTimeout', true);
  }`, it means that only if you specified `timeout` to `true` ,the driver would send the noCursorTimeout flag. So I've no idea why you made it

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who stumbles upon this one on latest MongoDB drivers, be aware of the following. If you call `.hasNext()` twice after the last `.next()` call, you will get: `Error: Cursor is closed`.

For example:

```
while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
    await cursor.next();
}

if (await cursor.hasNext()) {} // Error!

if (!cursor.isClosed() && await cursor.hasNext()) {} // Correct way
```

Comment: I also have the "Cursor is closed" issue while using for..of, thanks for providing this information, is it documented?

Comment: I faced the same error, and as you said, I'm calling method twice, not the `hasNext()` but the method `.next()`. Thanks for pointing out this code error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i resolved it by pushing each document of the cursor on a list and then returning the list, as shown here:

```
const list:any= [];
const cursor= await client.db('insertYourDb').collection('insertYourCollection').find().forEach(function(document) { 
        list.push(document) 
    });
return list;
```

Comment: This would be a really bad idea since you are going to exhaust the memory. It is identical to doing a find().toArray() only much slower.